# How to prepare PDF transparency for printing

Tags: adobe-illustrator, print-design

I'm using illustrator to create a piece of artwork. I've used several transparent layers (small circles). Since I'm using a transparent effect, **do I need to rastarize or flatten it?**

I tried flattening but those transparent circles changed back to their original color (back to 100%, no more transparency).

This is for commercial printer to make 1000 copies of it. I'm sending the files in PDF.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are sending files to Press as a PDF you needn't worry about transparency.

Simply save as a PDF/X-1a file and send it. All the transparency will be adjusted (flattened) as needed when saving the PDF. In general, there's nothing you need to manually do before saving a PDF/X-1a file.

Comment: thanks scott i was just about to bang my head against the wall considering about the fallatning and rastarizing i was gone mad whole night watching youtube and googling you are a my life saver god bless u bye the way then why we exactly use the flattning and rastarizing??

Comment: Flattening is sometimes needed for special circumstances, such as providing EPS files (but generally not PDFs). Rasterizing more of a last resort in terms of production.